# delete lines in a files using sed

Tags: linux, unix, sed, awk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [eliminate unwanted output using awk and sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9904555/eliminate-unwanted-output-using-awk-and-sed)

The following contents are there in a file. How can i delete all the lines that starts from `find: Filesystem loop detected;`?

```
find: Filesystem loop detected; `/nfs/.snapshot/nightly.4' has the same device number and inode as a directory which is 2 levels higher in the filesystem hierarchy. 
find: Filesystem loop detected; `/nfs/.snapshot/nightly.5' has the same device number and inode as a directory which is 2 levels higher in the filesystem hierarchy. 
find: Filesystem loop detected; `/nfs/.snapshot/nightly.6' has the same device number and inode as a directory which is 2 levels higher in the filesystem hierarchy.
Owner     RepoName             CreatedDate

asasasa s sasasas
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not `grep` ?

```
grep -v '^find: Filesystem loop detected;' myFile
```

Answer (score 1):

sed:

```
 sed '/^find: Filesystem loop detected/d' file
```

awk:

```
awk '!/^find: Filesystem loop detected/' file
```

grep is a good choice as well, as mouviciel pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways.

With sed, the easiest way is probably:

```
sed -n '1,/find: Filesystem loop detected/p' /path/to/logfile
```

Redirect the outpout into a temporary file, move that in place of the log file, then restart syslogd.

As to how the command works:

- sed -n is "do not print lines unless directed"
- 1, is "starting from line 1 until..."
- /.../  "this regular expression matches"
- p is "print line"